# Dynamically append child element on load in Polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to upgrade to Polymer 2.0 and I can't seem to append child elements on a parent element's load like I could in 1.X. Previously, I think I just used the `ready` callback, but it seems all the callbacks have changed.

Seen [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade) in the **Callback contracts have changed** section.

I've tried running

```
document.getElementById("parent-element").appendChild(document.createElement("child-element"));
```

on `ready` and `attached`, yet it seems to be executing the line before `parent-element` is even created. This causes an exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

I've also tried using

```
this.$.container.appendChild(document.createElement("child-element"));
```

where `container` is the `id` of an empty `<div>` inside the parent element, but I get the same issue. I'm pretty new to Polymer, so if there's a better method or structure I can use to get what I need, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 1.x -> 2.x [upgrade guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade):

> - For standard DOM operations, remove the Polymer.dom() wrapper.
> - Use this.shadowRoot in place of Polymer.dom(this.root).

The `ready()` callback is now asynchronous (microtask) due to the webcomponents v1 spec. To mitigate this, use `settimeout`, which is another task at the browser level and runs after microtasks. [Source of next code block](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#ready-time).

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
  setTimeout(function() {
    var distributedNodes = this.$.slot.assignedNodes({flatten: true});
    console.log(distributedNodes);
  }.bind(this), 0);
}
```

If you want to dig into tasks and microtasks [this blog post is a great read](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/).